# How do I delete an orphaned paragraph node?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have a paragraph node which seems to have gone rogue, since it does exist (I found it doing a search using Search API), but it does not appear as content, so I cannot delete it from the user interface.

How can I properly remove it?

Comment: Another option is to remove all orphaned paragraphs at once:-
[Drupal 8 ophan paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016160/drupal-8-orphan-paragraphs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not afraid to do it programmatically, you could use this code to load and delete the paragraph:

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph')->load($paragraph_id);
if ($entity) $entity->delete();
```

Comment: I have never done anything programatically in Drupal but I'm somewhat used to PHP so I might try your suggestion. But first, my excuses for two noobie questions: 1) As I'm not deleting all paragraphs (just the rogue one :-P)) should I replace `$paragraph_id` with the particular id? 2) As I'm not into programmatic Drupaling, should I implement your piece of code inside a module (or so)? Thanks.

Comment: 1. this is correct
2. you can put it in a theme hook like THEME_preprocess_html
BUT: Be sure the paragraph is not needed anymore and make a copy of the database

Comment: @Antonio I would rather do it from an external script that bootstraps Drupal and removes the paragraph. Editing a module or a theme just to add code that you need once is not very convenient, especially if you are doing it on a production server. The best would be doing it with Drush, if you can install/use it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno very convenient. I didn't know you could run PHP using Drush. I'll try that.

Comment: It works! Thanks to both of you! Being the fix to the main question I'm marking @alexej_d answer as correct.

Answer (score 9):

In Drupal 8, you can still use [`entity_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_delete_multiple/8.5.x), but it is marked as deprecated and it is going to be removed from Drupal 9.

It makes easy to remove those entities using Drush, for example, with the following code.

```
drush php-eval 'entity_delete_multiple("paragraph", [$id]);'
```

Even using code that works on Drupal 9, you would delete those entities in a single command line.

```
drush php-eval '$storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type); $entities = $storage_handler->loadMultiple([$id]); $storage_handler->delete($entities);'
```

Replace `$id` with the ID of the entity you are going to delete. You can also delete multiple entities at once replacing `[$id]` with an array of IDs.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually caused by the bug [Removed paragraph entities are not deleted from database](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2741937).  When that gets fixed, this problem will stop getting worse (bloating our databases).

To remove all of this no-longer-relevant data in a clean standard way, we need to get a solution to [[META] Remove obsolete composite entities from existing storage (garbage collection)](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_revisions/issues/2771531).

Rather than coming up with workarounds as suggested in other answers, patches for either (or both) of these issues would solve the issue permanently.

Comment: Yep, maintainers have asked many times for help with patches, tests, contributions.